# CORS issue using Dot Net Framwork 4.5.2 with Angular 6

Tags: c#, .net, angular, angular6

I am having CORS issue on app made in DOT NET FRAMEWORK 4.5.2 & Angular 6 on frontend
This is what I tried yet.

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
      // Web API configuration and services
      //EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "GET,POST");
      config.EnableCors();
    
      // Web API routes
 }
```

I tried with adding my localhost address as well. It didnot work.
The I added a CorsPolicy as well that didnt work too.

```
    public class MyApiCorsPolicy : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider
    {
        private System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy _policy;

        public MyApiCorsPolicy()
        {
            // Create a CORS policy.
            _policy = new System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy
            {
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };
        }

        public Task<System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Add the Request origin to the response.
            _policy.Origins.Add(request.GetCorsRequestContext().Origin);
            return Task.FromResult<System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy>(_policy);
        }
```

This above code is WebApiConfig.cs

This is StartUp.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); ConfigureAuth(app);
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}
```

[Image is also attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvJOn.png)

Comment: IServiceCollection requires external Nuget package. Have you tried it in Framework version 4.5.2? @alterfox

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes you'll need to make in your startup.cs file.  The first is in the "ConfigureServices" method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //.....
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyCorsSettings", builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins(MySettings.CorsAllowedDomains.ToArray())
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")
                    .AllowAnyMethod());
        });
    //.....
}
```

Note that in the above code MySettings.CorsAllowedDomains is just a string array of allowed domains (i.e. 'https://www.example.com') that is loaded from the appSettings.

The second change is in "Configure" and you need to pass in the same reference name (i.e. "MyCorsSettings")

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ....
                app.UseCors("MyCorsSettings");
    ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is slightly changed for .net core 6. In program.cs add service

```
//Add cross-orgin resources sharing services

//Defined to use with dev and staging environment
var AllowAllOrigins = "AllowAllOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
  
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", policy =>
           policy.WithOrigins("*")
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")
               .AllowAnyMethod());
});
```

//then add the middleware
app.UseCors(AllowAllOrigins);